# rnx2rtkp error : no nav data, convbin doesn't create .nav file

Tags: linux, post-processing, rtklib, rinex

I have U-Blox ZED-F9P receiver and antenna U-Blox ANN-MB-00-00. I'm trying to [create precise GNSS tracks](https://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?id=71718).

I never had such experience, so maybe I'm doing something wrong.

For recording, I use Armbian 22.02.1 with `gpsd` v3.22. For post-processing, I use Devuan 5 "daedalus" (based on Debian testing) with `rtklib` v2.4.3.b34.

Preparations:

```sh
export UBXOPTS='-P 27.12 -f /dev/ttyACM0'
ubxtool -e RAWX
ubxtool | fgrep RAWX
```

gives

```
UBX-RXM-RAWX:
UBX-RXM-RAWX:
```

Then I started to record a raw data (~570 KB for 11 minutes):

```sh
gpspipe -x 700 --raw > rover_700s_raw.ubx
```

In parallel, I downloaded a correction information from the nearest station (~750 kB for 15 minutes):

```sh
str2str -in 'ntrip://my-email@example.com:none@rtk2go.com:2101/Rychtal' -out /tmp/base_Rychtal.rtcm3
```

Then I convert them into `.obs`:

```
 $ convbin rover_700s_raw.ubx
input file  : rover_700s_raw.ubx (u-blox UBX)
->rinex obs : rover_700s_raw.obs
->rinex nav : rover_700s_raw.nav
->sbas log  : rover_700s_raw.sbs

scanning: 2022/05/07 22:16:30 GREC
2022/05/07 22:04:52-05/07 22:16:30: O=699

 $ convbin base_Rychtal.rtcm3
input file  : base_Rychtal.rtcm3 (RTCM 3)
->rinex obs : base_Rychtal.obs
->rinex nav : base_Rychtal.nav
->sbas log  : base_Rychtal.sbs

scanning: 2022/05/07 22:17:59 GREC
2022/05/07 22:02:50-05/07 22:17:59: O=910

 $ ls -l
total 4364
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 2515356 May 14 11:15 base_Rychtal.obs
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  756077 May  8 00:17 base_Rychtal.rtcm3
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  607734 May 14 11:17 rover_700s_raw.obs
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user  577720 May  8 00:16 rover_700s_raw.ubx
```

Then I tried to create NMEA with correction:

```
 $ rnx2rtkp -n rover_700s_raw.obs base_Rychtal.obs
error : no nav data
```

So I found I have no .nav file after `convbin` conversion…

I've tried different options for `convbin`, but anyway it woun't create anything else except of `.obs` file.

What I'm doing wrong? How should I create a track with correction?